# Trouver que vs. penser que

Tags: vocabulaire

I'm wondering if there's any difference between using **penser que** or **trouver que** in the following phrases:

> Depuis tout petit il pense/trouve que c'est pénible d'aller à l'école

> Même si sa voix est belle, il ne pense/trouve pas qu'elle marche avec cette chanson

> Elle pense/trouve que le français est une belle langue

Merci d'avance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"penser que" involves something reflexive (your belief rely on some reasoning) whereas "trouver que" is more spontaneous or perceptual

About your sentences, I would say

- Depuis tout petit il **trouve** que c'est pénible d'aller à l'école
- Même si sa voix est belle, il ne **trouve** pas qu'elle marche avec cette chanson

But

- Il **pense** que c'est le bon chemin (*He thinks it is the right way*)

Comment: Can you edit your numbered list? It's unclear what you're trying to say.

Comment: Your third suggestion doesn't match the OP question.